# Transforming rows into columns

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, pivot, transpose, unpivot

I have read countless threads on pivot and still unclear

**Table1**: This is what I have

```
Key Id Field1   Field2   
1   20   123     dkdf 
2   20   342     fe2f
3   20   894     lol3
4   20   093     09ps
5   20   999     393d
6   20   283     amls
7   20   kol     290f
```

**Table2**: This is what I want

```
Id   Field11 Field12 Field13 Field14 Field15 Field16 Field17 Field21 Field22 Field23 .....
20     123     342    894      093     999     283     kol     dkdf   fe2f     lol3  .....
```

---

Please let me know how would you go about doing this.

Thanks

Comment: Will you have the same number of rows for each `Id`?

Comment: No, number of rows for each id can vary from 1-22 in table 1. The columns in the second table on the other hand are fixed, equal to 22. 

I am using SQL Server 2008

Comment: I do not believe you can do it as pure `SQL query`. You will need dynamic `T-SQL` solution and there are plenty of them on the Web.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pivot the above table you can use code like:-

```
    select id, max(case when field1 = '123'  then '123' end) field11,
max(case when field1 = '342'  then '342' end) field12,
max(case when field1 = '894'  then '342' end) field13
from try group by id;
```

See the tested query in http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6ef0d/5

I have shown 3 columns as example. You can repeat the same for all columns. If you want to use Oracle pivot function then for that you ought to have aggregation function requirement in your query.

Comment: I can't use hard-coded values for any columns. I just need to take data in a column (all the rows) and have each row in a different column in the second table for a given id.